# OleDB and a dollar sign

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, worksheet

I manage an old application that imports an excel document. It has worked great for a long time but about 6 month ago, it stopped working. After searching for the error on and off for a couple of months I finally found out that I needed a $-sign at the end of the name of the worksheet in the `Exceldocument`.

The question, what could have changed this requirement? A new version of Excel? I know that the company that we get this document from, upgraded their Office suite but I haven't been able to confirm if this is the problem. We still get `.xls` files, so it should be the same I think.

Did something happen with Office?

Thanks in advance
Roland

Comment: I've never done an excel query without a dollar sign.  What is the new and old version of Excel?

Comment: [IFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) your code did not change, and you data did not change, then the change must be in the environment. As @cadrell0 said, you need to find the versions of office, and hopefully you'll be able to reproduce the results in your environment.  Note that even the latest versions of Excel can save xls files.

Comment: You can query named ranges, and they don't require a `$`, but they also don't require brackets (which worksheet names do).  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that the previous versions of the document had a named range that matches the worksheet name, and *that* is what you were querying before. When querying a worksheet, the `$` suffix is required, and always has been.